# VSCode creates empty .ipynb_checkpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I run Jupyter on a remote server via ssh inside VSCode. Everything works fine except that **Jupyter does not create any checkpoints**. However, it creates empty .ipynb_checkpoints folder.
If I start the browser version of Jupyter Notebook from the VSCode terminal, it saves checkpoints with no problems. I prefer the VSCode extension over regular Jupyter because it enables autocompletion and lots of other features. Still, I feel unsafe about not having an option to revert to a checkpoint.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong and how I could fix it?

VSCode version: 1.63.0
Jupyter Extension version: v2021.11.1001550889

settings.json

```
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "remote_server": "linux"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "window.autoDetectHighContrast": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "notebook.output.textLineLimit": 100,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "checkpoints.addCheckpointOnSave": true,
    "checkpoints.askForCheckpointName": false,
    "jupyter.generateSVGPlots": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem and would be interested in knowing!

Comment: @R.W. Unfortunately, no. Clean install, disable/enable of extensions, etc do not help at all. Initially, I thought it might be related to the remote server, but I am getting the same error on my local machine as well. If I find anything, will post it here!